# Asp.net Core not Collecting Garbage

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I can't seem to understand why Asp.net core is not collecting garbage. Last week I let a web service run for a few of days, and my memory usage reached 20GB. GC doesn't seem to be working. So to test this I wrote a very simple web method that return a large collection of strings. The application started off using only 124MB, but with each time I called the web method, the memory usage kept getting higher and higher until it reached 411MB. It would have gone higher if I had kept calling the web method. But I decided to stop testing.

[image]

Does anyone know why the GC is not working? As you can see from the performance monitor the GC was called (the yellow marker on the graph). But it did not collect the garbage from memory. I would think that the GC would eagerly collect anything that didn't have a reference to it.

Any help will be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks! :)

Comment: Don't think that is a proper test for garbage collection. Cause .net creates a heap in memory when it needs more memory. However when it collects it does not reduce the heap instantly. It will do it over time. Cause releasing the heap is a more resource intensive compared to creating. However, it should be reusing the same heap when calling multiple times. Can you try without the async. Just to see what is happending ?

Comment: Hi @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen, I've removed the async web method, and test again, but this time as a synchronous method. I am still having the same memory issue. So it doesn't seem like it's an async issue. Like you said, the same memory space should have been reused with every call. but with every call the memory usage goes up. This is a little disconcerting.

Comment: I also tested with both IIS, as well as with Kestrel. Unfortunately they both show the same behavior.

Comment: I've opened up a ticket on the asp.net github repository. Hopefully we'll get to the bottom of this. Here's a link to the ticket => https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1976#issuecomment-290685334

Answer (score 8):

I've ran into the same problem and after a long day found a solution in [one of the github issues](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/1899) registered for high memory consumption.

Actually, this is expected behaviour (in a multi-core high memory machine) and called "Server" garbage collection mode. This mode is optimized for server load and runs GC only when it's really needed (when it starts to lack memory in a machine).

The solution is to change GC mode to "Workstation" mode.
You can do this by adding a setting to your .csproj

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <ServerGarbageCollection>false</ServerGarbageCollection>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Workstation mode is meant to use less memory but run GC more often.

It is well-documented by Sebastien Ros here:
https://github.com/sebastienros/memoryleak

> On a typical web server environment the CPU resource is more critical
>   than memory, hence using the Server GC is better suited.

Comment: Also, workstation GC is better inside docker container (server collection is really "one big process" - thats not true for docker containers...) [source](https://dev.to/mortenrickirasmussen/the-single-best-tip-for-running-asp-net-core-microservices-3ho4) [source2](https://chuckconway.com/garbage-collection-types-in-net-core/) and [many more](https://www.google.com/search?q=.net+ServerGarbageCollection+docker)...

Answer (score 0):

The server is caching the output, 100,000,000 * 4 characters ~ 411MB.